# How to load property file from classpath in AWS lambda java

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

I have written AWS lambda function in that i want to read database connection details from property file and which in my classpath, but I am not able to load that file.Here is my code:

```
InputStream input = DBConfiguartion.class.getResourceAsStream("appsettings");

        Reader r = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(r);
```

If I run this code through normal java console application that time it is working, but whenever i run it as AWS lambda function then
**InputStream** is coming null.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are only one character off.  Here's a working example that I have to do the same thing:

```
InputStream is = DBConfiguartion.class.getResourceAsStream("/lambda.properties");
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(is);
```

This works with the following maven file structure when building the deployment jar:

- project
- project/src/main/java
- project/src/main/java/com/something/DBConfiguartion.java  -
- project/src/main/resources
- project/src/main/resources/lambda.properties

Comment: i'm having same problem as specified in the issue description. Now when i change the property file name to begin with forward slash(/), then my local JUnit test is failing.

Comment: @greg . Can you check below UdoHeld's solution. He is suggesting to use **ResourceBundle**

Answer (score 2):

As you want to load a properties file you can use the `ResourceBundle` to load the properties.

```
String version = ResourceBundle.getBundle("lambda").getString("version");
```

It's not the same as loading file as an `InputStream`, but this worked for me. In a maven project the file would need to be located at:

- project/src/main/resources/lambda.properties

I have a simple Hello-World Lambda which reads the current version from a properties file on [github](https://github.com/udoheld/aws-lambda-hello-log/blob/master/src/main/java/com/udoheld/aws/lambda/HelloLogSimple.java).

Comment: Hi, Udo.. Thank you for your suggestion. I was not aware of **ResourceBundle** before.