# AWS Lambda Java how to read properties file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I try to load properties into Properties class from a file. I would expect this solution to work: [How to load property file from classpath in AWS lambda java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356200/how-to-load-property-file-from-classpath-in-aws-lambda-java)

I have a class with few static methods and I want to use it as a Config holder. Inside it there is this line

```
final InputStream inputStream = 
Config.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/application-main.properties");
```

and it always returns null. I downloaded the zip package that Lambda is using and the file is inside in root. Does not work nevertheless.

Anyone had similar issue?

EDIT:
config file is here:

```
project
└───src
│   └───main
│      └───resources
│            application-main.properties
```

EDIT:
My "temporary" workaround looks like that:

```
// LOAD PROPS FROM CLASSPATH...
try (InputStream is = Config.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName)) {
        PROPS.load(is);
    } catch (IOException|NullPointerException exc) {
        // ...OR FROM FILESYSTEM
        File file = new File(fileName);
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            PROPS.load(is);
        } catch (IOException exc2) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not read properties file.");
        }
    }
```

During tests it reads from classpath, after deployment in AWS Lambda runtime it uses filesystem. To identify the file I used env variable:

```
fileName = System.getenv("LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT")  + "/application-main.properties";
```

But I would rather just use classpath without working this around.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming src/main/resources/config.properties

```
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("resources/config.properties").getFile());
FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
prop.load(fileInput);
```

Answer (score 2):

As you want to load a properties file you can use the `ResourceBundle` to load the properties.

```
String version = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application-main").getString("version");
```

It's not the same as loading file as an `InputStream`, but this worked for me.

I have a simple Hello-World Lambda which reads the current version from a properties file on [github](https://github.com/udoheld/aws-lambda-hello-log/blob/master/src/main/java/com/udoheld/aws/lambda/HelloLogSimple.java).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a .properties file in src/main/resource package, try this:

```
protected static Properties readPropertiesFile() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = Utils.class.getClassLoader();
    try {
        InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("PropertiesFile.properties");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(is);
        return prop;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can invoke it this way:

```
Properties _dbProperties = Utils.readPropertiesFile();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am confused a lambda is part of a serveless application. So when you upload the Lambda to AWS Lambda, it wont see the properties file. since that is in your dev env.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have the following folder structure:

```js
project
└───src
│   └───main
│      └───resources
│            config.properties
```

And your Lambda Handler:

```js
ClassLoader loader = Config.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream input = loader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

That may work...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried with and without the slash ("config.properties" and "/config.properties"). None worked.

Answer (score 0):

To solve something like this you can use `lightweight-config`, which is a library for loading `.yml` files into POJOs. This wraps up the boilerplate of finding the configuration file in your resources, and also handles interpolating things like environment variables or system properties into the configuration. This is much easier to use than `Properties` and removes all the boilerplate.

E.g.

```yaml
username: ${DB_USERNAME}
port: 3306
```

Then a java class to represent these (as `Properties` or `Map` are less type-safe):

```java
public class Config {
    private String username;
    private int port;

    // getters and setters
}
```

To load:

```java
Config config = ConfigLoader.loadYmlConfigFromResource("config.yml", Config.class);
```

The full library is available here - https://github.com/webcompere/lightweight-config